# App throws error on start after upgrading from kivy 1.11.1 to kivy 2.0.0. Any idea?

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

I'm an amateur coder making an app through kivy, and for some reason certain widgets cause the app to fail when I declare more than one instance of them. This issue only started after upgrading from kivy 1.11.1 to kivy 2.0.0. Here is one of the widgets that is causing the issue:

```
<LineCircle1@Widget>:
    onSwitch: 1
    ringActivate: True
    myRadius: 100
    myColors: [[.1, 1, .1],[1, 0, .1]]
    myColorCurrent: [1, 0, .1]
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: self.myColorCurrent if self.ringActivate == True else self.myColors[1]
            a: root.onSwitch
        Line:
            width: 2 if self.ringActivate == True else self.myRadius
            circle:
                (root.center_x, root.center_y, root.myRadius) if root.ringActivate == True else (self.center_x, root.center_y, root.myRadius/5)
        Ellipse:
            size: (2*self.myRadius,2*self.myRadius) if root.ringActivate == True else (0.01,0.01)
            pos: self.center_x-root.myRadius,root.center_y-root.myRadius
    center: self.center
```

Line 9 of the above code throws "IndexError: list index out of range" and line 12 throws "GraphicException: Invalid width value, must be > 0." Both of these errors only appeared after upgrading to kivy 2.0.0.

To isolate the problem, I have created minimum viable code which is available in the github link below. If only one LineCircle1 instance is declared, the app works. If both LineCircle1 instances are declared, the errors appear. Any help would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks!

URL: https://github.com/Ealt1/myTestApp

Answer (score 0):

I think you code should work, but it doesn't. A workaround is to declare the `LineCircle1` class in your `py` with some of the properties defined there:

```
class LineCircle1(Widget):
    myColors = ListProperty( [[.1, 1, .1], [1, 0, .1]] )
    myRadius = NumericProperty(100)
```

And the `kv` then becomes:

```
<LineCircle1>:
    onSwitch: 1
    ringActivate: True
    myColorCurrent: [1, 0, .1]
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: self.myColorCurrent if self.ringActivate == True else self.myColors[0]
            a: root.onSwitch
        Line:
            width: 2 if self.ringActivate == True else self.myRadius
            circle:
                (root.center_x, root.center_y, root.myRadius) if root.ringActivate == True else (self.center_x, root.center_y, root.myRadius/5)
        Ellipse:
            size: (2*self.myRadius,2*self.myRadius) if root.ringActivate == True else (0.01,0.01)
            pos: self.center_x-root.myRadius,root.center_y-root.myRadius
    center: self.center
```